# Sort a model by it's first related model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model, Reservation, which hasMany serviceDates.

Is it possible in Laravel (5.3) to sort my Reservations by their first service dates 'date' column?

I've tried this...

```
$reservations = Reservation::with(['serviceDates' => function ($q) {
                            $q->orderBy('date', 'asc');
                        }])->get();
```

...but this doesn't seem to work because a Reservation hasMany serviceDates and doesn't have have 1 serviceDate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that eager loading in Laravel does not join the related tables, it selects them in a separate query instead.

The easiest solution in my opinion is to add the latest serviceDate as a subselect to your query and order it by that:

```
$reservations = Reservation::select('reservations.*')
    ->selectRaw('
        (SELECT MIN(date) FROM service_dates WHERE reservation_id = reservations.id) as service_date
    ')
    ->orderBy('service_date')
    ->get()
```

You can still eager load service dates if necessary.

Comment: Close to exactly what I needed. Had to swap out the MAX for MIN though in my case to get the first date chronologically. With MAX it was showing someone with a first service date in May between two people in November because their last day was in November. Switching it with MIN returns the perfect result set. Thank you!

Comment: I just did. =] Might want to edit out your MAX for a MIN so it correctly answers sorting by the first date. Thanks a ton, have a good one